# Quisiera saber como puedo validar mi contraseña de una forma segura cumpliendo los requisitos para una contraseña fuerte en javascript?

Tags: javascript, formularios, validación

Hola tengo un archivo js llamado validar.js lo que quiero es validar que la cotnraseña cumpla los siguiente requisitos

1. Tenga ocho caracteres como mínimo.
2. Letras en mayúscula
3. Letras en minúscula
4. Numeros

```
function validar() {
    var nombre, apellido, identificacion, nacimiento, ciudad, correo, telefono, usuario, contrasena, rol, expresion;
    nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
    apellido = document.getElementById('apellido').value;
    identificacion = document.getElementById('identificacion').value;
    nacimiento = document.getElementById('nacimiento').value;
    ciudad = document.getElementById('ciudad').value;
    correo = document.getElementById('correo').value;
    telefono = document.getElementById('telefono').value;
    usuario = document.getElementById('usuario').value;
    contrasena = document.getElementById('contrasena').value;
    rol = document.getElementById('rol').value;

    expresion = /\w+@\w+\.+[a-z]/;


    if (nombre === "" || apellido === "" || identificacion === "" || nacimiento === "" || ciudad === "" || correo === "" || telefono === "" || usuario === "" || contrasena === "" || rol === "") {
        alert("Todos los campos son obligatorios");
        return false;
    }
    else if (nombre.length > 30) {
        alert("El nombre es muy largo");
        return false;
    }
    else if (apellido.length > 30) {
        alert("El apellido es muy largo");
        return false;
    }
    else if (identificacion.length > 12) {
        alert("La identificacion es muy largo");
        return false;
    }

    else if (correo.length > 50) {
        alert("El correo es muy largo");
        return false;
    }
    else if (telefono.length > 10) {
        alert("El telefono contiene 10 digitos");
        return false;
    }
    else if (usuario.length > 30 || contrasena.length > 30) {
        alert("El usuario o la contraseña superan los 30 caracteres");
        return false;
    }
    else if(contrasena.minlength < 8){
        alert("La contraseña de debe tener mas de 8 caracteres");
        return false;
    }

    else if (isNaN(telefono)) {
        alert("El teléfono ingresado no es un número");
        return false;
    }
    else if (!expresion.test(correo)) {
        alert("El correo no es valido");
        return false;
    }


}
```

tengo esta funcion que valida otros campos pero me quiero centrar ahora en la validación de una contraseña segura con los anteriores requisitos, de que manera lo puedo lograr teniendo la estructura que llevo

Answer (score 1):

aquí puedes encontrar los estándares de validación de formato de password mas comunes y recomendados

https://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/password-validation.php